# Как развернуть react приложение на сервере linux?

Tags: linux, reactjs, centos, развертывание

Есть сайт на react, который нужно перенести на сервер. Запустил у себя на компьютере

`npm run build`

`npm install serve -s`

`serve build -s`

На local-ip:3000 запустился сайт. Теперь переношу на удаленный сервер. Запустил из папки сайта /var/www/websitefolder

```
yum install npm
```

Перенес папку build в папку сайта. Затем запустил:

```
npm install serve -s
serve build -s
```

Получил

> не удается получить доступ к сайту

при переходе на remmote-ip-addres:3000.

Что делаю не так? Может 3000 порт на машине открыть надо?

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко, то да - нужно открыть порт 3000.

Если длинно, то я в таких случаях поднимаю на сервере `nginx` на 80-м и 443-м портах, и делаю внутри редиректы и обратную прокси.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

этот блок велит серверу все HTTP-запросы перенаправлять на HTTPS.

Доступ к вашему `react` серверу через фичу, которая называется *обратная прокси*:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name your.server.domain;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/your.server.domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/your.server.domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Здесь единственная тонкость - перед тем, как получить сертификаты у Let's Encrypt, нужно подпихнуть nginx-у какие-то сертификат и ключ, чтобы `https` завёлся. Без ключа и сертификата `nginx` отказывается запускаться. У меня всегда есть в загашнике ключики и сертификаты от других сайтов, но вы можете для себя сгенерировать самоподписной сертификат.

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr -subj '/CN=your.server.domain'
$ openssl x509 -signkey domain.key -in domain.csr -req -days 365 -out domain.crt
```

В результате `domain.crt` - самоподписной сертификат, `domain.key` - соответствующий приватный ключ. Укажите их в `ssl_certificate` и `ssl_certificate_key`, а затем запустите `nginx`.

После того, как `nginx` стартовал, вам нужно будет получить сертификат.

Я всегда пользуюсь бесплатными сертификами от `Let's Encrypt`, получаю их через `certbot`:

```
$ certbot --nginx -d your.server.domain
```

В результате профит: по адресу https://your.server.domain/ находится ваше приложение.