# Настройка Nginx для react Не могу получить доступ к сайту

Tags: reactjs, windows, nginx, centos, развертывание

Помогите коректно задиплоить приложение на удаленный сервер.

У меня на компьютере windows. на Сервере Centos. Поставил на сервер nginx. Домена у сайта пока нет, но даже с ssl ключом (генерировал сам) не выходит получить доступ к сайту. Хочу развернуть на 81 порту (на 80 уже стоит версия на php). Отредактировал дефолтный конфиг таким образом:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


server {

        root /var/www/website_folder/build/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name Machine_IP;

        location / {
                   try_files $uri $uri/ @application;
        }
        
        location @application {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
   


}
server {
    if ($host = Machine_IP) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 




        listen 81;
        listen [::]:81;

        server_name Machine_IP;
    return 404; 




}
```

Ssl сертификат и ключ сгенерировал командой

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
```

Далее запустил build папку на 3000 порту через

`serve -s build`

из (website folder) (Файлы сборки лежат в /var/www/website folder/build). Получил не удается получить доступ к сайту при переходе на Machine_ip:3000 и Machine_IP:81. Задавал похожий вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508156/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-react-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-linux), но там не было nginx.

`nginx -t` ошибок не выдает. React билдил у себя на локальном компьютере с настройками по умолчанию. Без `homepage` в `package.json.`

Объясните, пожалуйста, все подробно, что пропустил и что не правильно. А то уже второй день бьюсь.

При переходе на Machine_IP:81

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе на Machine_IP:3000

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вкладке response

> Faild to load resourse data: No resource with given Identifier found

Запрос идет на Machine_IP:81/ или 3000/ соответственно.

Добавляю Access log

```
5.188.210.227 - - [27/Mar/2023:05:52:14 +0000] "\x05\x01\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
5.188.210.227 - - [27/Mar/2023:05:53:21 +0000] "\x04\x01\x00P\x05\xBC\xD2\xE3\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
5.188.210.227 - - [27/Mar/2023:05:54:47 +0000] "GET http://5.188.210.227/echo.php HTTP/1.1" 400 657 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36" "-"
34.77.127.183 - - [27/Mar/2023:07:27:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 644 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2" "-"
176.113.115.51 - - [27/Mar/2023:07:41:07 +0000] "GET /remote/fgt_lang" 200 644 "-" "-" "-"
18.135.100.190 - - [27/Mar/2023:09:17:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 644 "-" "'Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net'" "-"
18.135.100.190 - - [27/Mar/2023:09:20:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 644 "-" "'Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net'" "-"
18.135.100.190 - - [27/Mar/2023:09:23:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 644 "-" "'Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net'" "-"
```

Добавил 4 последние Записи error log

```
[emerg] 29908#29908: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[notice] 31036#31036: signal process started
[emerg] 29908#29908: still could not bind()
[notice] 31156#31156: signal process started
```

Nginx запущен.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ошибки, которые вы получаете. Второе, посмотрите логи nginx и приложения (если реализовано). Вопрос в том где затыкается запрос. Я бы еще запросы поотсылал через curl или postman какой нибудь, чтобы понять, что происходит

Comment: @Dmitry Сейчас добавлю вывод консоли в google chrome

Comment: @Dmitry Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не очень информативно, не указывает на проблему, смотрите логи nginx. Там вообще что нибудь есть? Ощущение, что до него и не доходит

Comment: @Dmitry Добавил Access log

Comment: @Dmitry Добавил error log

Comment: Сколько конфигураций nginx существует? Почему указывается занятым 80 порт, хотя в конфиге он не указан. Чтобы увидеть весь конфиг, который применяется запустите `nginx -T` с заглавной буквой `T` и посмотрите, что вы имеете на выходе. И относительного этого надо действовать

Comment: @Dmitry после nginx -T  получаю мой нужный измененный дефолтный конфиг. Есть еще конфиг в папке sites-available. Его создавал вчера, но не получилось его привязать, поэтому удалил nginx через yum remove nginx и поставил заново. Потом изменил дефолтный конфиг.